# How to properly notify the data service of all modifications when imperative apex method is called from LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-data-service, transaction

Per the documentation [Refresh the Cache When Calling a Method Imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_result_caching) we need to notify the lightning data service that we used an imperative apex method to modify some records in order for it to process those modifications appropriately. That's easily done for the records that were directly a part of our DML but how to we notify the data service about other records that may have been updated by automation as a result of our changes? Obviously this is pretty tough given that there isn't a System.getTransactionDMLIds() function that would return ids for all records edited in the transaction (and even if such a function existed it would have to be called at the end of the transaction which is a problem in and of itself). Guessing this is just not a supported use case but wanted to check to be certain anyway.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like this. You'll have to create your own notification mechanism to do this I would think.  I'm not sure the exact route to do this, but it will probably need some combination of change data capture and a lightning message channel